# My code does not import sql into the database

Tags: php, mysql, error-log

```
$model_1="ticketdokan";
$view_1="false";
$sqlfile3="insert into notification_user values(NULL,:uid,:model,:text,:time,:view)";
$resfile3=$connect->prepare($sqlfile3); 
$resfile3->bindparam(":uid",$fet_buyer['id']);
$resfile3->bindparam(":model",$model_1);
$resfile3->bindparam(":text",$url[2]);
$resfile3->bindparam(":time",$time);        
$resfile3->bindparam(":view",$view_1);
$resfile3->execute();
$resfi4=$resfile3->errorinfo();
var_dump($resfi4);
```

Where is the problem with this code?My code does not import sql into the database

Comment: My error : array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }

Comment: Where did you assign values for $fet_buyer, $url, and $time?

Comment: $fet_buyer===User ID       $time===Time and Date Now   $url[2]=== url second

Comment: you should edit your code to include the assignments. The triple = is a comparison operator and "User ID" does not seem like the correct value for $fet_buyer.

Comment: Kadm was healthy, only his position was wrong. Thanks to all the participants